# Fine-Tuning a Circuit After changing VCA (SSM2641 to SSI2164)

Tags: analog, audio, filter, repair, voltage-controlled-amplifier

A friend's accident led to a fried SSM2641 VCA in an Eurorack audio module. Determined to give it a new lease on life, I'm diving in, though VCAs are not my forte.

After searching for hours, it seems there's no direct "plug and play" replacement available, correct? Only SSI2164, a near-identical VCA. However, its input impedance differs from the original SSM2641.

Will I need to tune the resistors and capacitors to align with the SSI2146's requirements? If so, could anyone help me with this? Your assistance would be greatly valued!

[image: Original Circuit for one Channel]

Here are the datasheets for both VCAs:

- [SSM2146 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/SSM2164.pdf)
- [SSI2164 Datasheet](https://www.soundsemiconductor.com/downloads/ssi2164datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you. But the datasheet claims _"The SSI2164 will directly retrofit existing SSM/V2164 positions while offering improvements [..]."_ Doesn't that imply that you can use it as direct replacement without further modifications?

Comment: I overlooked that aspect. I'll definitely give it a shot, but I've come across discussions on mod forums suggesting adjustments might be necessary when swapping. Appreciate you pointing that out, thank you!